# ruby on rails 4.2 - ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Prodotti#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html but i'm stuck on section 5.2 'the first form'

The error is after i put **prodotti_path**

```
<%= form_for :prodotto, url: prodotti_path do |f| %>
```

my rake routes:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
 welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
prodotti_index GET    /prodotti(.:format)          prodotti#index
               POST   /prodotti(.:format)          prodotti#create
  new_prodotti GET    /prodotti/new(.:format)      prodotti#new
 edit_prodotti GET    /prodotti/:id/edit(.:format) prodotti#edit
      prodotti GET    /prodotti/:id(.:format)      prodotti#show
               PATCH  /prodotti/:id(.:format)      prodotti#update
               PUT    /prodotti/:id(.:format)      prodotti#update
               DELETE /prodotti/:id(.:format)      prodotti#destroy
          root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

but when i refresh the page http://localhost:3000/prodotti/new/ the rails say:
**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Prodotti#new**

Why? i'm new to ruby and ror, sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to the Rails community!

---

Here's what you need to do:

```
#app/controllers/prodottis_controller.rb
class ProdottisController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @prodotti = Prodotti.new
   end
   def create
      @prodotti = Prodotti.new prodotti_params
   end

   private

   def prodotti_params
       params.require(:prodotti).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
#app/views/prodotti/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @prodotti do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :attribute_name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**OOP**

The problem you have is you're using a symbol in your [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). Whilst this *does* work, it is not the best way to get it working, especially for a beginner.

Without going into too much detail, I'll explain that `form_for` is what's known as a *helper* method. If you pass this certain credentials, it will construct an HTML form for you:

> Typically, **a form designed to create or update a resource reflects the
>   identity of the resource** in several ways: (i) the url that the form is
>   sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a
>   request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the
>   appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource), (ii)
>   input fields should be named in such a way that in the controller
>   their values appear in the appropriate places within the params hash,
>   and (iii) for an existing record, when the form is initially
>   displayed, input fields corresponding to attributes of the resource
>   should show the current values of those attributes.
>
> In Rails, this is usually achieved by creating the form using `form_for`
>   and a number of related helper methods. **`form_for` generates an
>   appropriate form tag** and yields a form builder object that knows the
>   model the form is about. Input fields are created by calling methods
>   defined on the form builder, which means they are able to generate the
>   appropriate names and default values corresponding to the model
>   attributes, as well as convenient IDs, etc.

This basically means that you're meant to pass objects to the `form_for` helper - objects which have been built in your model and assigned in your controller.

The *objects* in Ruby are used by Rails throughout your application. Indeed, as Ruby is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), all the things you do with the language, and frameworks, are meant to revolve around objects too.

Rails is object orientated in its own way. Remember, Rails is a *framework* which sits on top of Ruby. Thus, anything you do has to have *objects* at the center of the flow:

[image]

Models construct the objects in Rails.

*Everything* from your routes to controller actions take the idea that your models will be invoking data objects -- making it that each "helper" method in Rails (such as `form_for`) can be used with the corresponding objects you've built.

This is why I recommended setting the appropriate variable and passing it to your form helper. This will tie into your routes and controller actions, and should work for you.

Comment: nice man, you help me a lot! You know some easy (correct) tutorial for beginner? I know already pattern mvc, i'm from php framework! But i want to learn ruby and rails too

Comment: GoRails.com is great, railstutorial.org is another good one for beginners. RailsCasts.com was good but now stopped. Sumurails.com is another :)

Comment: I'm in love with Laravel